# Thread hangs after producer.send()

Tags: java, multithreading, glassfish, jms

I wrote the following piece of code to send a message to the consumer. It works as long the consumer is alive.But I am testing what happens if the consumer goes down. So I have the following class.

```
public class MyConnection{
Producer producer;

private void init(String brokerAddress){
     com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory myFactory = new com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory();
     myFactory.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqAddressList, brokerAddress);
     myFactory.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqAckOnProduce, "false");
     myFactory.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqConfiguredClientID, "clientId");
     myFactory.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqEnableSharedClientID, "true");
     javax.jms.Connection conn = myFactory.createConnection();
     session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
     this.producer = session.createProducer(session.createTopic("SOME_TOPIC"));
     myFactory.getProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqAckOnProduce);
     connectionStatus = BROKER_CONNECTED;
}
//Message is of type javax.jms.Message  
private send(Message message){
  boolean paramterSent = false;
  try
  {
     producer.send(message);
     paramterSent = true;
  }
  catch (JMSException e)
  {
     connectionStatus = BROKER_DISCONNECTED;
     logger.log(Level.INFO, "Could not send message to EPS ", e);
  }
  return paramterSent;
}
```

So what I am testing here is I am calling init() and creating the connection then I am killing the broker which recieves the messages. and then I am trying to call send so I expect it to throw and JMXException but it doesn't and it hangs at producer.send() and on the console I get this message.

```
Dec 5, 2013 9:14:54 AM com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ExceptionHandler logCaughtException
WARNING: [I500]: Caught JVM Exception: java.io.EOFException: Trying to read 72 bytes. Already read 0 bytes.
Dec 5, 2013 9:14:57 AM com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ConnectionRecover logRecoverState
INFO: [I107]: Connection recover state: RECOVER_INACTIVE, broker: localhost:31300(31301)
Dec 5, 2013 9:15:21 AM com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ExceptionHandler throwConnectionException
WARNING: [C4003]: Error occurred on connection creation [10.187.37.188:31300]. - cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

I am using the following

```
Oracle GlassFish(tm) Server MQ Destination
getName():      SOME_TOPIC
Class:          com.sun.messaging.BasicTopic
getVERSION():       3.0
isReadonly():       false
getProperties():    {imqDestinationName=SOME_TOPIC, imqDestinationDescription=A Description for the Destination Object}
```

What i found from investating is that in package com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.MessageProducerImpl class, checkReconnecting method it is not able get a lock on the object reconnectSyncObj so it is trying to get access to it but not able to so its hanging. Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: I changed some names to comply with my company policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by closing the connection whenever the broker is disconnected. I did this in the onException method of the javax.jms.ExceptionListener.

```
 public void onException(JMSException exception)
      {
         try
         {
            connection.close();
         }
         catch (JMSException e)
         {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Connection Failed", e);
         }
      }
```